# help with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a webpage which I have designed in firefox, yet when I open it Internet explorer and resize it so its NOT maximum size (half page or so) half of the main div dissapears under the footer.

www.blisshair.com.au

its the first page that opens, The page looks perfect in firefox, resized or not, but when trying in Internet explorer it only looks fine when the page is maximum size, if resized the design completely breaks.
Any help or tips on how and where this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much.

EDIT: it is only happening when the file is uploaded to the web, when previewing on my localhost server it displays as its meant to?

Comment: please mention the version of `IE` IE6,7,8 or 9

Comment: At IE6 it looks really terrible

Comment: is there any way to view the page in IE6? i am installing VMware at the moment, to install IE 6 as am running windows 7 x64 and IE 6 doesnt appear to be compatible.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your site to have a better chance of working in all browsers you should really apply some standards. Using http://validator.w3.org to validate your HTML there seems to be 16 errors. Fixing these errors will probably make it work in IE correctly.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.blisshair.com.au&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: No problem! Also, if you want to check it in multiple IE's try IE Tester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 1):

If you take the min-width off, or lower it to 600px. This will fix the problem in IE.

Comment: That's on the table.diffTypes class.

Comment: thanks :) editing the min width for content, table.difftypes, and wrapper fixed the problem, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the css of the id 'content', particularly below attribute

```
#content { overflow: hidden; }
```

After that, you may set width for the  that show product description on the right side of image or modify padding/magin if the text got truncated for your designed website's resolution.

Comment: thanks :) editing the min width for content, table.difftypes, and wrapper fixed the problem, thank you very much :)